# setInterval with play() in flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm trying to play a sound (notification sound) in my flash application and I need to play the sound until the user clicks on something else to stop it.

I can play the sound properly but the issue is that it will only play once but i need it to play constantly (a short delay between each play maybe?).

my current code is this:

```
    var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
    mySound.load(new URLRequest("iphonenoti_cRjTITC7.mp3"));
    mySound.play();
```

so I thought I can use `setInterval(mySound,5000);` in my code but this doesn't work which means it doesn't play the sound on the loop!

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, reading the [Documentation of setInterval](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval()) it states that the first parameter should be a **function**. In your code, you are passing an **Object** of the type `Sound`.

So, there are a couple of options, I'll show you the quickest and dirtiest one.

Instead of `setInterval(mySound,5000);` you write `setInterval(mySound.play,5000);`

Comment: Excellent... as i posted this question, I found another solution to my problem as well.... it was easy.. all i had to do was this:  `mySound.play(0,6);`  this will play the sound 6 times....

Comment: That's also possible. You can also implement a loop (with ENTER_FRAME for example), wait until the sound has finished playing by observing its values, and when it finishes call `play` again. Like I said, there are a bunch of options.